# popover display abnormal in iOS8,but normal in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios8, popover

1. The display abnormal in i0S8,but normal in i0S7. Please look the link:
   http://pan.baidu.com/s/1sjkAzZB
2. The related code:

   ```
   WEPopXSaveMenu *contentViewController = [[WEPopXSaveMenu alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
   contentViewController.selxNotifyView = self;
   CGRect frame = ISAPPSCHEMA_PAD ? CGRectMake(912, 30, 40, 10) : ISAPPSCHEMA_POD568 ? CGRectMake(473, 2, 50, 32) : CGRectMake(385, 2, 50, 32);

   self.podInfoWepopover = [[[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];
   [self.podInfoWepopover  presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view 
                                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                   animated:YES ];
   ```

I can't find the different between on iOS8 and iOS7, please help me.Thanks.

Comment: First of all, iOS8 is still in beta so there are could be problems. On the other hand, during the WWDC main Apple developers said that popover will be added to iPhone as well as to iPad. So probably, they changed the behaviour of that component.

Answer (score 0):

Under the first tab in the File Inspector on the left in the Storyboard layout, uncheck "Use Autolayout"   under Interface Builder Document.

[image]